# Send Discord messages from Tkinter GUI via discord.py

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, discord.py

I am trying to use the discord.py library to send messages to a channel using it's name.
This library is asynchronous and I have problems with sending more than 1 message. when I try to send a message afer the `send` function has already been called, I get this

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<send() done, defined at C:\Users\paula\DiscordBot\Bot.py:65> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine')>
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
```

the send function :

```
async def send():
    global en_message, en_ChannelName
    guild = client.get_guild(some_guild_ID_you_want)
    for channel in guild.channels:
        if en_ChannelName.get().lower() in channel.name.lower() and type(channel) == discord.channel.TextChannel and en_ChannelName.get() != "":
            await channel.send(en_message.get())
            break
```

the code it is called by :

```
bt_Send = tk.Button(text="Send", command=partial(client.loop.create_task, send()))
```

I also have to mention that the discord client is running on a non-main thread
(the code :

```
thread_runBot = t.Thread(target=partial(client.run, botToken))
thread_runBot.start()
TK_dialog.mainloop()
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you can't use a coroutine twice.

There's a way to get around this though. You can create a class with a custom `__call__` that changes the behavior when it tries to be called.

```py
class CoroutineCaller:
    def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
        # you can also use `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task` if this doesn't work
        client.loop.create_task(send(*args, **kwargs))

sender = CoroutineCaller()
```

When you do `sender()`, it will create a *new* coroutine and add it to the client loop.

You can then do something like this:

```py
bt_Send = tk.Button(text="Send", command=sender)
```

---

Here's an updated version that lets you call *any* coroutine multiple times.

```py
class CoroutineCaller:
    def __call__(coro, *args, **kwargs):
        client.loop.create_task(coro(*args, **kwargs))
```

You can call this like `caller(ctx.send, 'random message', embed=discord.Embed(title='test'))`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, It really helped me out with that case.
Do you know if there is a way to pass such a class any function you want to be able to be awaited multiple times without rewriting it by hand every time?

Comment: Yes, see the edited answer. You can supply any function object and then have it call it multiple times. The only thing that matters is that a new one is generated each time, which that does.